# npm windows installation proxy issue

Tags: node.js, npm, installation

I am using below commands to setup proxy on window7

```
npm config set proxy http://<username>:<password>@<proxy-server-url>:<port>
npm config set https-proxy http://<username>:<password>@<proxy-server-url>:<port>
```

but I am not able to setup proxy correctly and when I am trying to run the command

```
npm config get proxy
```

I am getting erroneous proxy URL as below

```
http://<username>/:<password>@<proxy-server-url>:<port>
```

and

**it seems slash before colon between "username:password" is getting added incorrectly as "username/:password"**.

**How do I correctly configure npm proxy on windows?**

Comment: http://<proxy-server-url>:<port> worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

write command in cmd(admin):
this work for me in w10

```
npm config set https-proxy http://username:password@proxy:port
```